# Create labels and richtextboxes dynamically

Tags: c#, wpf, list, label

I'm trying to make x amount of labels and rich text boxes next to the labels appear when an event is triggered, unfortunately I have been unable to do so, the code below shows my attempt at creating the `labels` part only with `5 labels` only but it doesn't even display them when the project is compiled and executed.  I've searched Google all day yesterday and this morning but I have not been able to find concrete examples.  If anyone could please point me in the right direction (I still have to make the rich text boxes but I think that is the same process as the labels) I'd very much appreciate it. Thanks.

```
List<Label> labels = new List<Label>();

for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
{
    Label label = new Label();
    label.Name = "lbl" + i;
    mainPanel.Children.Add(label);
}
```

`Edit:` I forgot to mention these `Labels` and `RichTextBoxes` will go inside a `Grid`.

Comment: I don't see you populating the `Content` property of the Label anywhere, so perhaps your labels are being generated but they're just left blank so you don't see them? Also, a better solution would probably be to just bind an [ItemsControl](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/09/17/wpf-itemscontrol-example/) to an `ObservableCollection<T>` of your data, and set the `ItemTemplate` to be a `Label` (or a `RichTextBox`, or both)

Comment: Thank you Rachel! You were right, apparently the labels were being created but not populated, my bad :).  I believe I'm not using WPF the way it is meant to be used, I browsed over to your blog entry http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/ but the idea is not quite getting into my head, I'll have to read your blog a few more times to see if it becomes a bit clearer then.  Do you know any other resources that explain what you explain in your blog but with a broader view and more examples like Guides or tutorials? - Thanks!

Comment: Did you read my article [What is this "DataContext" you speak of?](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2012/07/14/what-is-this-datacontext-you-speak-of/)? It explains that WPF has a data layer and a UI layer, and the UI layer is only supposed to be a user-friendly interface for interacting with the data layer. It would probably help the most with explaining how WPF works. (The [Blog Articles](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/blog-articles/) link at the top also contains a section of tutorial-ish posts I've written for WPF/MVVM beginners if you're interested)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you very much for your help, what you posted here actually helped me a lot, however, I solved my problem by using this code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < lineCount; i++)
{
    TextBlock txtb = new TextBlock();
    scrlPanel.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());

    txtb.Name = "txtb" + i;
    txtb.Text = obj.ReadLine();
    txtb.Height = 60;
    txtb.Width = 110;
    txtb.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
    txtb.TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Justify;
    txtb.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;
    txtb.ToolTip = txtb.Text;
    scrlPanel.Children.Add(txtb);
    Grid.SetRow(txtb, i);
}

for (int i = 0; i < lineCount; i++)
{
    RichTextBox rtb = new RichTextBox();
    Paragraph p = rtb.Document.Blocks.FirstBlock as Paragraph;

    rtb.Name = "rtb" + i;
    rtb.Height = 60;
    rtb.Width = 220;

    p.LineHeight = 1;
    rtb.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Right;
    scrlPanel.Children.Add(rtb);
    Grid.SetRow(rtb, i);
}
```

I don't know if it's the correct way to use this but it works :D. Thanks again!!!

Answer (score 2):

Your code's nearly there.

Change mainPanel.Children to mainPanel.Controls
and add some text to the labels so you can see them. (BTW you're creating 6 labels not 5 as you used 0 to 5 instead of 0 to < 5)

This worked for me inside a flow layout panel (in a regular panel all the labels will sit on top of each other):

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<Label> labels = new List<Label>();
        for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
        {
            Label label = new Label();
            label.Name = "lbl" + i;
            label.Text = "Test text";
            mainPanel.Controls.Add(label);
        }

        List<RichTextBox> textBoxes = new List<RichTextBox>();
        for (int col = 0; col < 2; col++)
        {
            for (int row = 0; row < 2; row++)
            {
                RichTextBox richTB = new RichTextBox();
                richTB.Name = "textBox" + col + row;
                tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(richTB);
                tableLayoutPanel1.SetColumn(richTB, col);
                tableLayoutPanel1.SetRow(richTB, row);
            }
        }
    }
```